# El asterisco no funciona como selector en una terminal con python

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con el código, en teoría debería usar todos los archivos con la extensión PNG en una carpeta. El argumento que es carpeta/*.PNG en Linux funciona pero en Windows no, cree que *.PNG es una carpeta.

Comment: eso es un tema de Bash: si no hay ningún elemento, no expande y considera `*.PNG` un literal.

Comment: No sé si lo he entendido bien. Pero el problema es con Windows y el CMD y es que al agregar ese argumento como entrada lo reconoce como carpeta

Comment: haz una prueba en una consola UNIX: ejecuta esto `for f in *bla; do echo "$f"; done`. Luego haz `touch hola.bla; touch adios.bla` y vuélvelo a ejecutar. En el primer caso, como no hay ningún fichero que encaje con "*bla", itera sobre este literal; en el segundo caso, itera sobre los ficheros cuyo nombre encaja con el patrón.

Comment: eso no me ha resultado, lo primero suelta un no se esperaba f en este momento